# Jquery debugging issue

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on a wp e-commerce system and I've managed to customized it according to my needs. I'm facing a pretty annoying problem by now. I'm not that familiar with javascript and jquery though I've figured out where the issue might be. I'm struggling finding a solution though.

The problem: Based on a form (select menu) a ajax function is called and the price changes and it does, though not on the correct product. Instead it is changing the last element every time.

Snippet from the jquery function which I think handles this specific aspect

```
// update the price when the variations are altered.
jQuery(".wpsc_select_variation").live('change', function() {
    jQuery('option[value="0"]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    parent_form = jQuery(this).parents("form.product_form");
    if ( parent_form.length == 0 )
        return;     
    form_values =jQuery("input[name='product_id'], .wpsc_select_variation",parent_form).serialize( );
    jQuery.post( 'index.php?update_product_price=true', form_values, function(response) {
        var stock_display = jQuery('div#stock_display_' + product_id),
            price_field = jQuery('#product_price_' + product_id),
            price_span = jQuery('#product_price_' + product_id),
            donation_price = jQuery('input#donation_price_' + product_id),
            old_price = jQuery('#old_product_price_' + product_id),
            save = jQuery('#yousave_' + product_id),
            buynow = jQuery('#BB_BuyButtonForm' + product_id);
        if ( response.variation_found ) {
            if ( response.stock_available ) {
                stock_display.removeClass('out_of_stock').addClass('in_stock');
            } else {
                stock_display.addClass('out_of_stock').removeClass('in_stock');
            }
        }

        stock_display.html(response.variation_msg);

        if ( response.price !== undefined ) {
            if (price_field.length && price_field.attr('type') == 'text') {
                price_field.val(response.numeric_price);
            } else {
                price_span.html(response.price);
                old_price.html(response.old_price);
                save.html(response.you_save);
            }
            donation_price.val(response.numeric_price);
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

And a snippet of the matching html which displays the prices.

```
<p class="pricedisplay <?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" id="">
                            <!--<?php // _e('Price', 'wpsc'); ?>:-->
                                <span id="product_price_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" class="currentprice pricedisplay">
                                    <?php echo wpsc_the_product_price(); ?>
                                </span>
</p>
```

I think it might be due to the jquery selecting the last element instead of a specific id.

I thank you very much in advance for your help. It is appreciated.

/nickifrandsen

Comment: Where do you set `product_id` in the javascript code?

Comment: i guess it is this line... price_span = jQuery('#product_price_' + product_id) though I'm not quite sure as my javascript syntax skills sucks a bit.